# PowerShell bug? Can't pipe ComputerName property to Get-Service (mixing byvalue and bypropertyname)

Tags: powershell, parameters, pipe, pipeline

Seems like a bug, no?  In this case, PowerShell converts the hashtable to a string '@{computername=comp001}' and tries to use it with -Name (ByValue) instead of -ComputerName (ByPropertyName).  Even PS 6 does it.  Piping to `Get-Service -Name *` works fine.

```
PS C:\> [pscustomobject]@{computername='comp001'} | get-service
get-service : Cannot find any service with service name '@{computername=comp001}'.
At line:1 char:45
+ [pscustomobject]@{computername='comp001'} | get-service
+                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (@{computername=comp001}:String) 
[Get-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand
```

Comment: -ComputerName parameter has been removed from Get-Service in PS 6.x, but seems like a bug in lower versions

Answer (score 4):

> Seems like a bug, no?

Not a bug as such, but an unexpected consequence of the parameter design of the `Get-Service` cmdlet:

**Attaching the `ValueFromPipeline` attribute to a parameter typed `[string]` / `[string[]]` or `[object]` / `[object[]]` (or `[psobject]` / `[psobject[]]`) makes that parameter bind to *any* pipeline input**, possibly *in addition to* binding to other parameters - *unless* that parameter is bound by *command-line argument*, which is what your `-Name *` workaround does.

- The reason is that instances of *any* data type can be converted to `[string]` / are derived from `[object]` (`[psobject]`), causing *any* input object, irrespective of type, to bind to that parameter.

In short: **the problem here isn't that `[pscustomobject]@{computername='comp001'}` *isn't* bound to `-ComputerName`** - it actually *is* - it is that **it is *also* bound to `-Name`, invariably.**
The PowerShell **parameter binder fundamentally binds pipeline input to *all* suitable parameters**, not just one.

As stated, the only way to prevent the `-Name` binding from the *pipeline* is to pass a value by *argument* - even if that value is just `*` to signal inclusion of services of any name.

The behavior is now also being discussed [on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7159).

---

Side note:

As js2010 (the OP) points out, **it *is* possible to meaningfully combine the `ValueFromPipeline` and `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` attributes in a *single* parameter**, the way `Get-Service` does, but note the constraints:

- It **only works for a parameter *not* typed `[object]` or `[psobject]` / `[object[]]` or `[psobject[]]`** (such a parameter would invariably bind everything *by value* without ever considering *properties*).

  - **If the type is `[string]` or `[string[]]`, properties *are* considered, but you cannot have *additional* pipeline-binding parameters**, because that presents the original problem: the `[string]` / `[string[]]` parameter will invariably *also* bind.
- The type of an input object's property matching the parameter name must either match the parameter type or must at least be *convertible* to it in order to be bound.

Here's a sample command that binds the same service to `-Name` first as a string and then as an object with a `.Name` property:
`'rpcss', [pscustomobject] @{ Name = 'rpcss' } | Get-Service`

Answer (score 2):

As you are sending a complete object to `Get-Service`, it has only two options for binding: `Name` and `InputObject`, which are the parameters that accept `ByValue` pipeline input.  Unfortunately, your object is not in a form that either understands.

You can see what PowerShell is doing by running this `Trace-Command`:

```
Trace-Command -Name ParameterBinding -PSHost -Expression {[pscustomobject]@{ComputerName='comp001'} | Get-Service}
```

As you say, the way around this is to supply a value for `-Name`, so it doesn't attempt to bind it:

`[pscustomobject]@{ComputerName='comp001'} | Get-Service -Name *`

Once again, you can use `Trace-Command` as above to see that it is now happy to bind '*' to `-Name`, then it goes on to bind the additional parameters like `-ComputerName`.

The PowerShell documentation ([about_Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters?view=powershell-6)) states:

> When a parameter is "True (by Value)", Windows PowerShell tries to
>   associate any piped values with that parameter before it tries other
>   methods to interpret the command.

Comment: I don't know where this is documented, but Get-Service has a -ComputerName option that can be piped in by property name.  There's probably other examples where the pipe byvalue parameter (string) takes precedence over the pipe bypropertyname of another parameter.

Comment: But converting a hash table to a string?  Where would that be useful?

Comment: Converting objects to strings is a fundamental operation, which is why every .NET object has a `ToString()` method (even hashtables).  How useful it is depends on the particular situation.  In this case, it's really a matter of "if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail".  `-Name` only accepts and understands strings, so if you give it _anything_ else, it doesn't know any better than to treat it as a string.  I guess what you were hoping is that it would decide that the input wasn't a string to start with and default to binding `ByPropertyName`, but that's not how it works.